# is rails like scaffolding possible in django? to perform list, view, edit and delete on database collections

Tags: django

i'm a newbie django developer, trying to build demo pages for my cpp and python programs. i have used ruby-on-rails some years ago.

i wish to know if there is any easy way to display the contents of a database collection on a django application. i'm using mongodb but any other example is fine too. i remember ruby-on-rails, using its scaffolds, provides a readymade solution to manipulate (list, view, edit etc) a database collection. is there a django equivalent?

i have gone through the django_mongodb tutorial to perform such manipulation myself. i mean, by writing the model, view and the template. but wondering how more experienced developers automate this process.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/) you'll find the [answer to your question](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/).

Comment: thanks. i have learned how to connect to mongodb from django from the tutorials. however, doing pagination, form validation etc in django seem non-trivial for a cpp/python programmer like me :( hence i was hoping to find a package or a third party solution which makes database manipulation easier. for example, in ruby-on-rails, views for listing, editing etc can be generated like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-scaffolding.htm).

Comment: His question has to do with scaffolding, not mongodb - and the answer is the [admin contrib app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/), which is detailed in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about the same issue. And I found [this article](http://www.krishnabharadwaj.info/django-scaffolding/) with announcement of [application django-groundwork](https://github.com/madhusudancs/django-groundwork) that can do something similar to `rails genereate scaffold` command, but without all sweet options.

As documentation says:

> This app does all the groundwork needed to get an app up and running..
>   Usage:
>
> Include django-groundwork and the newly created app in your list of
>   installed apps. Create the models.py file for your app with all the
>   fields specified.
>
> Run the following command
>
> $ manage.py groundwork appname ModelName1 ModelName2

I'm really thinking to fork this application and to add support for generating models with fields and other good necessary stuff..

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot closer to rails scaffolding: https://github.com/modocache/django-generate-scaffold

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [django-addview](https://github.com/yakxxx/django-addview). It allows you to easily generate views (also class based). It also creates template and edits urls.py for you.

Full disclosure: I wrote it.